# How to draw circle in mapbox_gl flutter using radius

Tags: flutter, mapbox-gl

I would like to add multiple circles using mapbox_gl package of flutter, so far I have did this

```
void _add() {
    List koordinat = [
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
      LatLng(...,...),
    ];
    List radius=[75.0,85.0,120.0,30.0,30.0,50.0,30.0,30.0];
    for (int i = 0; i < koordinat.length; i++) {
      mapController.addCircle(
        CircleOptions(
            circleRadius: radius[i],
            geometry: koordinat[i],
            circleColor: "#97F1F6",
            circleOpacity: 0.6),
      );
    }
  }
```

but the thing that makes me confused is... is it true that the unit of circleRadius is in metres here?

Comment: it should be in pixels

Comment: do you know a way to add circle by metres unit instead of convert it?

Comment: make a function which converts pixels to meters . sort of this : double returnMeters(int radiusInPixels){return (1/0.377952755906) * radiusinPixels; }

Comment: I will try it, thank you very much for your help

Comment: sorry I have given you a reverse function. What you programme wants is meters to pixels . Use this :  double returnPixels(double radiusInMeters) { return 3779.52755906 * radiusInMeters ; }

Comment: @gladiator I want to make sure... pixel for each device is different, so I need to combine it , right